# Two ways to compute divergence do not agree

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

We can compute the divergence of a vector filed $X$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ expressed in polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ in two ways: the first one is the [classical formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates)

> $$\text{div}(X)=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial(rX^r)}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial X^\theta}{\partial\theta},$$

and the second one is the formula given by the Riemannian definition of the divergence (here $(x^1,x^2)=(r,\theta)$)

> $$\text{div}(X)=\frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^i}+\Gamma_{ij}^iX^j=\frac{\partial X^r}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial X^\theta}{\partial\theta}+\frac{1}{r}X^r.$$

The two expression are not the same: the term $\frac{\partial X^\theta}{\partial\theta}$ is rescaled differently. Why? I suppose that it has something to do with some kind of renormalisation.

For the Christoffel symbols I looked [here](http://einsteinrelativelyeasy.com/index.php/general-relativity/29-christoffel-symbol-use-case-calculation-in-polar-coordinates).

Comment: This is not the Riemannian formula for divergence with which I'm familiar. Where did you get this? Ultimately, you should use the metric to convert $X$ to a $1$-form $\omega$, apply the Hodge star operator to get an $(n-1)$-form $\star\omega$, apply $d$, and then $d{\star}\omega = \text{div}\,X\,dV$. The Christoffel symbols aren't involved.

Comment: In my geometry class, but you can find it here for instance: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137573/divergence-of-a-vector-field-on-a-manifold

Comment: Got it: It's the trace of the covariant derivative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that the first formula comes from taking components of $X$ with respect to the orthonormal basis $e_r,e_\theta$, whereas the  differential geometry formula is in terms of components with respect to the coordinate basis $\partial/\partial r, \partial/\partial\theta$. In particular, the unit vector $e_\theta = \frac1r\partial/\partial\theta$. So the $X^\theta$ appearing in the two formulas are different.